# android studio Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm struggling to load an image using its file name instead of its ID.

```
public static Bitmap load(String name) {
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dir + "/res/drawable/" + name + ".png");
}
```

This is all I got so far, but it throws this FileNotFoundException:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/res/drawable/image.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I have also added these permissions to the android-manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

I really have no idea why its throwing the exception, which path do I use to decode a file from the drawable folder actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load drawable resource this way. Resources are bundled in apk, they are not stored as files. You should use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` instead.

Read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)